# es6 classes and react component methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

I'm workin with react components and es6.
How should I use logic from onChange method into other method?

```
render() {
    let input;
    return (
<tr>  <input 
        ref = {node => { input = node; }} 
        onChange = { event => {
            if (input.value === this.props.word.pl) 
                event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'Chartreuse';
            else if (input.value !== this.props.word.pl)
                event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'LightCoral';
            else if (input.value === "")
                event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'none';
            }
        }/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what "How should I use logic from onChange method into other method?" means. It is not very clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move your function out on a component level
2. Bind this in the constructor
3. Use it on multiple onChange events

---

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // bind this
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  // reusable function
  handleChange(e) {
    // ... your logic for onChange here
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Read more about React forms [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: Since the we are using ES6 here, why not use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) when defining component level functions. This way we wont have to bind inside the constructor.

Comment: because then you would recreate the function on every rerender, which has performance implications (for shallowEqual on shouldComponentUpdate)

Comment: If you don't mind using experimental ES features ([through Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), or something like it), you can use arrow functions without the overhead by making use of class properties. See https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus#arrow-functions.

Answer (score 2):

Leo, gave you an example of how to bind your methods in the constructor. But I will give you one more example on how can you avoid binding in the constructor.

**Arrow functions syntax**:

```
handleChange = e => { ... }
```